# Changing specific observation color (value text) with sgplot - forest plot

Tags: sas, sgplot, forest-plots

I am currently writing an sgplot code for forest plot (SAS University edition). I have managed to get the correct graph as I want, however I can not change the color of a specific observation. This is my code

```
data my_data;
    input study $ year rr lcl ucl;
    datalines;
    mickey 2015 1.5 0.7 2.3
    minny 2010 1.2 1.0 1.4
    donald 2013 0.8 0.2 1.4
    daisy 2014 1.3 1.0 1.6
    goofy 2017 1.9 0.9 2.9
    pluto 2010 1.4 0.7 2.1
    ;
run;

proc sgplot data=my_data
            noautolegend nocycleattrs; 

    scatter y=study x=rr/ markerattrs=(symbol=squarefilled size=12 color=black);
    highlow high=ucl low=lcl y=study / type=line lineattrs=(color=black);

    yaxistable study year / labelattrs=(family=arial size=12pt weight=bold) position=left location=inside valueattrs=(family=arial size=10pt);
    yaxistable rr lcl ucl / labelattrs=(family=arial size=12pt weight=bold) position=right location=inside valueattrs=(family=arial size=10pt);

    xaxis offsetmin=0.1 offsetmax=1 min=0.5 max=3.0 display=(nolabel);
    yaxis offsetmin=0.1 offsetmax=0.1 display=none reverse;

    refline 1 / axis=x;

    styleattrs axisextent=data;  
 run;
```

What I am trying to achieve is changing observation number 3 (donald, 2013, 0.8 0.2 1.4) into a red color (the text when plotting, not only the marker attributes).

I have tried to check for different sgplot attributes, but I am not able to change this specific color of observation number 3 (as red, and other observations remain black) when plotting. I have also looked at template, but this does not help. How can I achieve this?

Comment: How are you making the decision to set it to red?  In other words, it would be trivial to set just one specific point to red - by writing an annotation or something - but it would be entirely hardcoded.  Is there a programming logic that defines why it's red?

Comment: @joe : basically if study is "Donald" or if "rr" is less than 1.0 then set it to "red"

Comment: Okay, then you can just modify that logic in my answer (if you explicitly want "id=donald").

Comment: @joe: I did not write correctly in the description, what I need is the words to be red (the text value of "donald 2013 0.8 0.2 1.4" when plotted) and not the marker only.

Comment: Then you assign `textcolor` not `markercolor` or whatever in the attribute map.

Comment: @joe : thanks for pointing out about the attribute map!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is some programming logic behind the decision, one approach is to create a dummy group variable.  Here I assume the logic is `rr < 1.0`.

I remove add `colorgroup` and `attrid` to the yaxistable in question.  You can change what colors are assigned to the groups (to restore black for the majority) fairly easily, either by using an attribute map as I do below (most correct) or a few other options including editing the default graph colors.

```
data my_data;
    length groupvar $20;
    input study $ year rr lcl ucl;
    if rr < 1.0 then groupvar='redgroup';
    else groupvar='blackgroup';
    datalines;
    mickey 2015 1.5 0.7 2.3
    minny 2010 1.2 1.0 1.4
    donald 2013 0.8 0.2 1.4
    daisy 2014 1.3 1.0 1.6
    goofy 2017 1.9 0.9 2.9
    pluto 2010 1.4 0.7 2.1
    ;
run;


data attrmap;
length value $20;
input value $ textcolor $;
retain id 'colorgroup';
datalines;
redgroup red
blackgroup black
;;;;
run;

proc sgplot data=my_data
            noautolegend nocycleattrs dattrmap=attrmap; 

    scatter y=study x=rr/ markerattrs=(symbol=squarefilled size=12 color=black) group=groupvar attrid=colorgroup;
    highlow high=ucl low=lcl y=study / type=line lineattrs=(color=black);

    yaxistable study year / labelattrs=(family=arial size=12pt weight=bold) position=left location=inside valueattrs=(family=arial size=10pt)  
                            attrid=colorgroup colorgroup=groupvar;
    yaxistable rr lcl ucl / labelattrs=(family=arial size=12pt weight=bold) position=right location=inside valueattrs=(family=arial size=10pt) ;

    xaxis offsetmin=0.1 offsetmax=1 min=0.5 max=3.0 display=(nolabel);
    yaxis offsetmin=0.1 offsetmax=0.1 display=none reverse;

    refline 1 / axis=x;

    styleattrs axisextent=data;  
 run;
```

Comment: Modified per the change in OP.